# Proof that: $I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=((I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I have to verify if the statment:

$$I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=((I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^2$$

is true or not. (I do not get to demonstrate).

Any help or hint will be very useful for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not just simply take the product?

$X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

Comment: ¿But, is the statement true? @Sayan

Comment: Let $P = I - X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$, and note that $PX = 0$.

Comment: @Mike13 Note that $X^TX(X^TX)^{-1}=I$

You are assuming that inverse exists. Although the original result is true even if generalised inverse is used

Comment: @Sayan Post it as answer and it would look better

Comment: @M.Vinay : I think it's a bit more conventional notation to write $P = X(X^TX)^{-1} X^T$ and let $Q=I-P$.  Also, sometimes $P$ is denoted $H$ and called the "hat matrix", and sometimes the letter $P$ is reserved for the case where $X$ is a column of $1$s, so $P$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose every entry is $1/n$. But none of this is sacred; notations vary. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me warn everyone who reads this that $X$ is **not** supposed to be a **square** matrix; it is a matrix with typically many more rows than columns.  Its columns must be linearly independent since otherwise $X^T X$ is not invertible.

Let $H= X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$.  Then
$$
H^2 = \Big( X (X^TX)^{-1} X^T \Big) \Big( X (X^TX)^{-1} X^T \Big) = X \Big( (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X) (X^T X)^{-1}\Big) X^T
$$
and then the obvious cancelation yields
$$
= X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T = H.
$$
Next,
$$
(I-H)^2 = (I - H)(I - H) = I^2 - HI - IH + H^2 = I - H - H + H = I-H,
$$
so $I-H$ is idempotent, i.e. it is its own square.

Comment: You are right @Michael Hardy.  X is not supposed to be independent. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @Mike13 independent $\neq$ invertible; careful with your language there

Comment: @Michael Hardy And it is true also that $$I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=(I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T$$ .

Answer (score 1):

$P_X = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$ is known as the **projection matrix** onto $\mathcal{C}(X)$, the column space of $X$. Note that since $r(X^TX) = r(X)$, if $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix, $X$ needs to have rank $p$.

Your statement is equivalent to showing that $I - P_X$ is idempotent.

Observe
$$(I - P_X)^2 = (I - P_X)(I - P_X) = I^2-2P_X+P_X^2\text{.}$$
Now
$$P_X^2 = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T} = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T} = P_X$$
and obviously $I = I^2$, so $(I - P_X)^2 = I - 2P_X + P_X = I - P_X$, as desired.

Comment: And it is true also that $$I−X(XTX)−1XT=(I−X(XTX)−1XT)T$$

Comment: @Mike13 You should probably ask this as a different question, but yes, it is. The reason why it is is because $I$ is symmetric and $P_X$ is symmetric because
$$P_X^T = [X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T]^{T} = X[(X^TX)^{-1}]^{T}X^{T} = X[(X^TX)^T]^{-1}X^T = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$$
because, obviously, $(X^TX)^T = X^TX$. It follows that $$(I - P_X)^T = I^T - P_X^T = I - P_X\text{.}$$